# How to call click function on input tag

Tags: jquery

How to call `click` function on input tag when I press in to the input field or change the value in the field like.

```
jquery('input').click();
```

I can't figure it out how to do I have checked [other places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click)?

Comment: `jquery('input').on('focus',function(){....});` is what you are looking for?

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking. Do you want to trigger the event, or attach an event handler?

Comment: please show your code, so we can see what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the

```
jquery('input').keypress(function (){'body'})
```

or

```
jquery('input').keydown(function(){  'body'; })
```

function it will trigger when you will press any key.

Answer (score 0):

I would use 'document' .on as it is a bit more reliable then the .click() although producing the same end result.

```
jQuery(document).on('click','input', function(){
    // do something
});
```

Comment: Though your code might answer the question, you should at least add a short description of what your code does and *how* it actually solves the problem.

Comment: Fair point. I have updated it accordingly. Sometimes I just think code. Thank you for the advice.